# Is every cumulative probability density function Borel measurable?

Tags: self-study, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

I have seemingly simple question, which does not need to have a simple answer :)

Is every cumulative probability density function Borel measurable?

Comment: Seems like a typical homework question, maybe add the self-study tag?

Answer (score 5):

**The answer is *Yes*. I leave the details out due to the homework nature of the question**

The following observation is useful:

> If $F: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $\mathcal E$ is a family of subsets of $\mathbb R$ such that $F^{-1}(A)\in\mathfrak B (\mathbb R)$ for every $A\in \mathcal E$, then $F$ is $\left( \mathfrak B(\mathbb R),  \sigma(\mathcal E)\right)-$measurable.

Note now that if we take $F$ to be an increasing function, then it is relatively straight forward to prove that $F^{-1}(t, \infty) \in \mathfrak B(\mathbb R),\forall t\in \mathbb R$.

We are done owing to the facts that distribution functions are increasing and that intervals of the form $(t,\infty)$ generate $\mathfrak B (\mathbb R)$.